# Detecting navigation events blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can I detect when URL is changed? I need the event (URL change event) to perform some specific action based on the URL.

Comment: Just alert or confirm ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you please share your code and where exactly you run into issues?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `NavigationManager` which has built-in `LocationChanged` event.

To handle the event you can inject the NavigationManager like this:

```cs
@inject NavigationManager nav
```

To show the alert you may need to add the JSRuntime too:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime js
```

and subscribe to the event with overriding `OnInitialize()`

```cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    nav.LocationChanged += (o, e) => {
        js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Alert"); // when location is changed invoke alert js function
    };
}
```

You can check the repl of this example in this link: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wabkuybC54SQD88I53